# Inserting date/time in a SQL table in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I am having a little issue inserting the date time into a database table name (TestTable) in SAS EG. The date fields in the TestTable are defined as

```
Name = EnteredDate  
Type = Date
Length = 8
Format = DATETIME22.3
Informat = DATETIME22.3

Name = LastUpdateDate  
Type = Date
Length = 8
Format = DATETIME22.3
Informat = DATETIME22.3
```

My existing code is as follows, where i use a select statement to insert as opposed to a values statement. Here is call a PrepTable which I dont use at all, but the select statement allows me to use the datetime() function which works perfectly in inserting the date time without any issues. See below:

```
INSERT INTO LIBNAME.TestTable (Statuscode, EnteredDate, LastUpdateDate)
Select '2', datetime(), datetime()
From work.PrepTable
```

I want to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO LIBNAME.TestTable (Statuscode, EnteredDate, LastUpdateDate)
VALUES ('2', datetime(), date time())
```

This is far more efficient I think since I dont have to query the work.PrepTable. But datetime() will not work in a values statement. I tried the following variations

```
INSERT INTO LIBNAME.TestTable (Statuscode, EnteredDate, LastUpdateDate)
VALUES ('2', "&sysdate9:00:00:00"dt,"&sysdate9:00:00:00"dt)
```

This method does not enter the time only the date and the date entered is wrong as well. Another variation I tried is the following after looking around on this site

```
INSERT INTO LIBNAME.TestTable (Statuscode, EnteredDate, LastUpdateDate)
VALUES ('2', &today_dttm,&today_dttm)
```

where &today_dttm is sourced from:

```
%let today_dttm=%sysfunc(dhms(%sysfunc(today()), 0, 0, 0));
```

This hasn't worked to well either as i keep getting only just the date inserted and not the time. Is there a proper way to enter the current day and time when the insert statement is called without having to use the Select statement and datetime() combo.

I am a newbie to sas and any input would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different issues here.

First off, `&sysdate9.` and `&sysdate.` are only [defined at system startup](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/68140/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0psau13pzzhf2n1mndr75gw7vc8.htm).  To get the current date, you need `%sysfunc(today(),date9.)` or `%sysfunc(datetime(),datetime17.)`.  You could use that in a values statement.

Second, I don't tend to encourage use of the values statement in SAS, because it's pretty minimal in what it supports compared to other SQL flavors.  I find it better to insert data using datalines in a SAS dataset and then appending that dataset.

```
data to_insert;
 input statuscode $;
 entereddate=datetime();
 lastupdatedate=datetime();
datalines;
2
;;;;
run;

proc append base=libname.testtable data=to_insert;
run;
```

Third, your various attempts to use date variables/functions (`&sysdate9`, `today()`) are not including the time because they're date variables/functions and don't include times.  Really what my first suggestion is, is simply combining two of your methods, after all.  While it is possible to have a decimal-containing date value in SAS which converts to datetime complete with h/m/s, it's not the "norm" unless your data comes from somewhere else (like excel).

Comment: Thanks Joe, this is very helpful. I never thought of using a data step to insert. I will give this a shot. Just thinking out loud here, will this data step to insert become challenging if i have to insert say 50 columns of data sourced from a prep table that might have multiple rows of this 50 columns? In which case I will have to use an interator and then have the data step within the iterator to insert every row. Correct me if my line of thinking is not right. Given you the green check and the helpful +1 to your answer

Comment: You can simply insert the entire dataset, using `PROC APPEND` (or other methods, but that's usually fastest and easiest).  You don't even have to specify the columns (as long as their names match up - don't have to be same order, just same actual names).

Comment: Ok thanks again, I will give this a go using larger datasets and see if i can time the performance using iterator vs proc append. Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: one limitation of using cards / datalines is that they cannot exist within macro definitions.  Of course macros should not be used for inserting large amounts of data (but then neither should .sas files really).  Something to consider..

Comment: Sure, none of this really should be used for anything significant - but a lot of SQL folks are used to inserting little bits here and there directly in code.  I would rather all of my data come in a dataset :)

Answer (score 2):

Joe's answer covers it, but here is a solution using your SQL.

You almost have it.  Try this

```
%let today_dttm=%sysfunc(datetime());
INSERT INTO LIBNAME.TestTable (Statuscode, EnteredDate, LastUpdateDate)
VALUES ('2', &today_dttm,&today_dttm);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot DomPazz, much appreciated with your response. I have given you +1 and a green check mark for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the `%let` part, just do this:

```
INSERT INTO LIBNAME.TestTable (Statuscode, EnteredDate, LastUpdateDate)
VALUES ('2', %sysfunc(datetime()),%sysfunc(datetime()));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score -2):

These may be useful. They work in WPS, a SAS-compatible system:

```
%let now=datetime();
%let yesterday=intnx('dtDay',datetime(),-1);
%let today=intnx('dtDay',datetime(),0);
%let tomorrow=intnx('dtDay',datetime(),1);
```

You can expand on that idea, then use them in your PROC SQL:

```
PROC SQL;

SELECT &today as today FORMAT=datetime., &tomorrow as tomorrow FORMAT=datetime.
FROM tablename
;
```

for example.